# Values are not entering into textbox after selection from calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, calendar

I have enabled required field validator for txtProjectDate textbox, which is not allowing the calendar to be poped-up after clicking the button for calendar.So, i cannot select values to be entered in to the textbox.
ERROR:Mandatory Field

ASPX FILE

```
 <tr>
            <td>Project Started at</td>
            <td>::</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtProjectDate_TextChanged1"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShowCalendar" runat="server" OnClick="btnShowCalendar_Click" ImageUrl="D:\calendar4.png" />
               <asp:Calendar ID="calProjectDate" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="calProjectDate_SelectionChanged" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvProjectDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtProjectDate" ErrorMessage="MANDATORY"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </td>
        </tr>
```

ASPX.CS CODES FOR textbox,calendar,button

```
  protected void btnShowCalendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            calProjectDate.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void calDateofBirth_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtProjectDate.Text = calProjectDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

            calProjectDate.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void txtProjectDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void calProjectDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtProjectDate.Text =
            calProjectDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            calProjectDate.Visible = false;
        }
```

Pls help me to find out the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `CausesValidation` attribute to false in `ImageButton`:-

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShowCalendar" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
       OnClick="btnShowCalendar_Click" ImageUrl="D:\calendar4.png" />
```

Comment: @KarthikPalchamy - You're Welcome :) Don't forget to accept it as answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work